# Has WMI "Event subscriptions" using WQL queries changed in Windows 10?

Tags: c#, events, usb, wmi, subscription

I have had a C# program running on Windows 7 which subscribes to USB insert/remove events with no problems (using the WMI API). On a Windows 10 machine the same program use excessive CPU. So I wonder, have the WMI implementation changed in Windows 10? See program code below:

```
 WqlEventQuery insertUSBDeviceQuery = new WqlEventQuery("SELECT * FROM __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 2 WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_PnPEntity'");
        insertWatcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(insertUSBDeviceQuery);
        insertWatcher.EventArrived += new EventArrivedEventHandler(DeviceInsertedEvent);
        insertWatcher.Start();
```

On Windows 10 this cause the WmiPrvSE.exe (WMI Provider Host) process to use roughly 30% of the CPU.

Any other ideas why we see a difference between Windows 7 & 10 here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We did not find an answer to this problem.
But since we knew exactly what devices we were looking for we ended up polling for data every 5s using this query.

```
using (ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(@"select DeviceID from Win32_PnPEntity Where DeviceID Like 'USB\\VID_" + vid + "&PID_" + pid + "%'"))
```

This was much more efficient and did not cause any CPU usage problems.